# Node.js find document by an element in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a user schema with the following structure:

```
new Schema({
            email : String,
            password : String,
            shoppingCart : [{type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Product'}]
        });
```

and I also have a product schema as follows:

```
new Schema({
            title : String,
            description : String,
            vendorId : String,
            stock : Number
        });
```

How could I search for the users which have a specific product within their shopping carts?
I tried both

```
UserModel.find({shoppingCart : product._id})...
and
UserModel.find({'shoppingCart._id' : product._id})....
```

but unfortunately it does not work. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried...

```
UserModel.find({shoppingCart : product})
```

If you use the actual object within the query, it will hydrate itself into ID and runs the search based on that object ID.

Since you have a Schema type as "Schema.Types.ObjectId" if you run

```
UserModel.find({shoppingCart : product._id})
```

It will search against product._id as "String" not ObjectId.

Comment: I think that this should be a comment, unless expanded into a full answer.